# Adding an extra field to all records in Firebase Realtime database

Tags: node.js, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to add a new field called calories:"" to every record in one of the tables within a specific child called "all"

The idea is loop through each record and do a .update adding the new field.

This is my code so far:

```
const addCalories = () => {
    const recipesRef= firebase
      .database()
      .ref("Recipes");
    
    recipesRef.on("value", (snapshot) => {      
      const recipes = snapshot.val();
      
      for (let id in recipes) {     
        recipesRef.child(id).child("all").update({ calories: "" });
      }
    });
  }
```

and this is a sample record structure

[image]

I'm getting the following error:

> Error: Reference.update failed: First argument  must be an object containing the children to replace.

To be honest, I'm not even sure if my approach is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably closer to what you want:

```
recipesRef.once("value", (snapshot) => {
  snapshot.forEach((child) => {      
    child.ref.child("all").update({ calories: 0 });
  }
});
```

The main changes:

- Use `once` instead of `on`, as you only want to make this change once every time this code executes. Using `on` would likely lead to many more updates than needed, and possibly to endless recursion.
- Loop over the results with the built-in `DataSnapshot.forEach` method, instead of a JavaScript `for` loop.
- Set the value to a numeric `0` instead of an empty string. I **highly** recommend storing numeric values as numbers, instead of strings.